# WinForms ReportViewer hangs the app WPF

Tags: wpf, report, reporting, reportviewer, rdlc

I've been experiencing some problems with the ReportViewer. Basically the code is the following:

```
public void Display(object dataSource, ReportViewer viewer)
    {
        currentDs = dataSource as MyTypes;

        if (currentDs != null)
        {
            var param = new LinkedList<ReportParameter>();
            param.AddFirst(new ReportParameter("Title", "Title"));
            viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            viewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = ReportName;
            viewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(DataSourceName + "_Header", currentDs.Header));
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(DataSourceName + "_Footer", currentDs.Footer));
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(DataSourceName + "_Lines", currentDs.Lines));

            viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);
            viewer.RefreshReport();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that sometimes it generates the rdlc report but others it just hangs the application. Specifically, it stays in viewer.RefreshReport(); forever.

The corresponding parameters and datasets are correctly set on the rdlc file.

Has anyone experienced a similar behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it occur randomly while using the same parameters?

Comment: yes it does. Sometimes hanging and others not with the same dataset.

Comment: i mine does your dataset all-way's contain the same values?

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger and pausing execution during one of these hangs? If so, can you add in the call stacks for the thread running this call?

Comment: @WiiMaxx, I'm working with Maxi on this and it seems to be data-invariant: run the same report w/ the same params against static data that has not changed, and sometimes the app hangs, and sometimes it doesn't. Everything points to some sort of elusive threading issue, possibly related to WPF. We haven't seen this before in a straight-up winforms app.

Comment: resolved or not ? do you have it repeatable to some extent ? did you try removing/cutting out. W/o (test) datasets (or some cut-down mode) - you can usually get down to one or few points of 'bother'. And that's why I don't like 'mixing the worlds', always trouble. Did you get the security right (btw anything special about the app?) - or e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263578/report-viewer-request-for-the-permission-of-type-sqlclientpermission-failed), asserting permissions. Also it seems to use own AppDomain. Are you running from the GUI thread? Or did you try moving it out?

Comment: @NSGaga, I just fixed it, I think. The report viewer form had to be created on the UI thread. So, first trick was to name the thread the app starts on, second trick was to force a handle and grab the synchronization context, third trick was to emulate InvokeRequired -> Invoke via the thread name + sync context. Now it all SEEMS to work. This page helped me get it working: http://ikriv.com/dev/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have fixed it. This page helped me figure it out: http://ikriv.com/dev/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html

So, it seems that a) report viewer needs to be created on the UI thread, and that b) that wasn't always happening reliably (see link for details). The report viewer is a .NET 2 component, and the behavior documented in the link applies to .NET 2.

To fix it, I employed the following tricks:

- first trick: name the UI thread at start up
- second trick: force a handle early on, then get a reference to the synchronization context
- third trick: use the thread name and sync context to effect the invoke required -> invoke idiom.

If it all holds together, I will come back and post w/ more details.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you have your viewer [configured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273267.aspx) correctly.

Does the first time generation usually succeed? You could try calling `viewer.Reset()` after each report generation, that might solve some compounding issues.

Answer (score 3):

There is [a post from 2006](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/83e2b62f-215d-4546-890c-85d9075cf269) that on the surface appears to be relevant and might give you a workaround, although I have to admit I haven't done this myself because it would be almost impossible for me to recreate the problem you're seeing and so it would be equally impossible to see if any workaround would fix it. It's not ideal, but I'm hoping there no such thing as useless information :-)

The relevant info is at the bottom of the linked thread and for the sake of clarity, I've quoted it below.

> The ReportViewer control is broken up into two components - the report objects (exposed as .ServerReport and .LocalReport) and the UI (the actual ReportViewer class).  The report objects store all of the state about your report.  The UI component simply calls into them to get the information it needs to display the report, parameter prompts, toolbar, etc.
>
> The UI component is not thread-safe, just like most controls.  But the report objects are thread safe.  When you call RefreshReport, the viewer uses a background thread to call Render on the report object.  But this is not the only time that the control calls into the report object.  The first time it needs to compile the report definition (local report) or create a session (server report) can take a long time.  If this "first time" is during RefreshReport, it will happen on the background thread.  But as you have seen, it can happen at other times.  Populating the parameters UI, for example, requires calling GetParameters, which also requires this startup penalty.
>
> If you want to guarantee this "first time" penalty is on a background thread, then after setting the report path and other connection/data source information, call GetParameters from a background thread.

This seems to suggest that you make some calls to your `ReportViewer` always from a background thread rather than from the UI thread, so that any delays are not affecting the UI. It sounds like a bit of a bodged design to me though!

Is this of any help to you?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the issue in Windows XP with .Net 4.0 and Report Viewer 2010. Yes the OS is end of support but Windows Embedded POSReady 2009 (Windows XP SP3), it's still in the extended support until April 2019.

To workaround the hang, call deprecated API to render the report

```
rptviewer.LocalReport.ExecuteReportInSandboxAppDomain();
```

and when exit or rerun the report e.g. report's parameters changed, the report need to clean up properly by

```
rptviewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
rptviewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = null;
rptviewer.LocalReport.Dispose();
// release sandbox is required to prevent the lock up, see below note on display report
rptviewer.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();

// clean up report viewer
rptviewer.Clear();
rptviewer.Reset();
```

Note on Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10. The hang issue is not occurred.