# Using Microsoft Report Viewer: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission' Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, permissions, reportviewer

### Problem Summary

I'm supporting an older ASP.NET intranet web application which is using the Microsoft.ReportViewer library.

When run, the report throws the following error:

> An error has occurred during report processing.
>
> The Sort expression for the grouping ‘list1_Details_Group’ contains an error:
>
> Request for the permission of type:
> 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

All my research suggests that this problem arises from the application not having the necessary trust levels (all relevant stack overflow questions were solved by setting trust level to full), but my web config defines the trust level at full, so I'm completely lost as to why this error is occurring.

I can't show all of the web config for security reasons, but the majority of it can be found here: http://pastebin.com/GdJhHDhH Anything missing has been commented or stubbed.

### Potentially Helpful Details

This problem arose after migrating the application from Forms Authentication to Windows Authentication. Not necessarily related, but hard to ignore the coincidence.

This problem is occurring across all my environments: Local, Dev and Prod (winding prod back to Forms Authentication makes this work).

The application is written in .Net 4, C#

The reporting code lives in a different assembly to the the web application, and the web application refers to the reporting assembly.

The web application successfully retrieves other data from the database in other areas of the application unrelated to reporting.

I'm at my wits end on this, any guidance would be great.

### Update: Attempted Solutions

Tried removing list1_Details_Group. When this is done, another part of the report throws the same exception.

Tried using impersonation with Windows Authentication. The application continued to work in the same way, while throwing the same exception in the report.

Tried Strongly Naming all assemblies used within the application. No The application continued to work in the same way, while throwing the same exception in the report.

Tried using the "Classic" Managed pipeline in IIS.

Comment: How do you pass credentials or authentication to reporting services ?

Comment: In terms of database credentials, the reporting service uses a connection string from the web config. In terms of Windows credentials, we use a custom MembershipProvider from my company's Nuget repository.

Comment: The MembershipProvider is only used/needed for Forms Authentication though. Windows Authentication should authenticate the user without any additional code (at least that's my understanding).

Comment: Have you tried to use impersonation with Windows Authentication. I'm not sure if it will help, but I think it's worth testing at least. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306158).

Comment: What happens if you remove `list1_Details_Group` from the report, do you then get the same error with another portion of the report? Are the Assemblies Strong Named: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2003/06/20/my-application-works-from-my-local-machine-but-throws-a-securityexception-when-i-move-it-to-a-network-share/ Although [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6106005/495455) is WinForms and yours is Web it has some permissions things to try, also have you tried with the policyFile, eg: `<trustLevel name="RosettaSrv" policyFile="rssrvpolicy.config" /`

Comment: I have tried impersonation, and unfortunately that didn't help.
and yeah, when I remove `list1_Details_group` I get the same issue with another element of the report.

I have also tried with the policy file.

I'll try out strongly naming the assembly and get back to you on how that goes.

Comment: Alrighty, I tried strongly naming all the relevant assemblies, but no dice, I'm afraid.

Comment: Where hosting ASP.NET intranet web application? If in IIS then try use "classic" app poll Instead of "integrated"

Comment: Thanks Gurgen, I am running it in IIS, so I'll give that a try.

Comment: Unfortunately using the classic app pool pipeline didn't resolve the exception, but it also stopped the routing in the app from working correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I know this is an old post. But I started having the exact same issue and could not find any solutions posted anywhere, so I'm posting my solution here.

ASP.NET 4.5, ReportViewer 11. Moving from Forms Authentication to Windows Authentication. Sorting in the report works fine in Forms Authentication, but I get a security/permission error with Windows Authentication.

I was able to reproduce the above both on the a Windows Server 2012 R2 as well as my local Windows 10 development environment (Visual Studio 2015).

What I found is that that I only get this issue when sorting across multiple columns with a `SortExpression` like the following:

```
=Fields!glp.Value & Fields!building_number.Value & Fields!room_number.Value
```

If I just do a simple sort on a field without a sort expression everything works fine.

I have *Full Trust Set* and all related properties in my `Web.config`—obviously, because it works with Forms Authentication.

#### Solution

To resolve this, set the permissions for the sandbox as follows:

```cs
rvReservations.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
LocalReport local_report = rvReservations.LocalReport;
local_report.ReportPath = "Reports\\rReservations.rdlc";
local_report.DataSources.Clear();

local_report.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(new System.Security.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted));
```

> ***Note:*** You will get the same behavior if you are passing parameters to your report; the same solution also applies.

Comment: Thanks very much for contributing! I no longer have access to this system to confirm whether this answer solves the problem, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Ran into this issue with a new release this week.  What's odd is the code related to the generation of the report has been in production for 4+ years.  The new release changes did not involve this code.  The solution solved the issue but any concerns on using it production under load?

Answer (score 2):

A few issues may be happening.

The first and most obvious, take a look at the error, it says

> The Sort expression for the grouping ‘list1_Details_Group’ contains an error

Let's address that first. Start by going to the Sorting property and find the associated group **list1_Details_Group**. If you've removed it and the issue is still present, then you'll have to look into the .rdl code and do a find for **list1_Details_Group**. If you find instances of it, it means it's still around. Clean those up.

**Additional notes:**
The second thing you need to look into is other "variables" may be affecting your setup. It has been [reported](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/586223/SecurityplusExceptionpluscomingplusinplusaplusrunn) that this issue could be caused by a third=party plugin or DLL. Have you added any third-party DLLs that weren't part of the original environment that only came into play at the time of switching to Windows Authentication?

Hope this helped in any way to get you on the right track.

Comment: Have a quick read through the comments on my question if you like. I've tried removing the list1_Details_Group (including doing so in the code-behind). When I did that, the same exception was thrown by a different part of the report. I'll try to find out if there are any other 3rd party plugins and DLLs causing the issue and let you know what I turn up.

Comment: My bad, I missed some of the comments. I'll keep an eye for other possible solutions. Best of luck.

Comment: I know this is kind of overkill, but have you considered [recreating](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application) the project and adding the code/components one by one?

Comment: It's not something I've tried yet, because the application is reasonably large. But I could perhaps try adding the minimum components required for the report to run, and see if that works, and if it does, slowly add the rest of the application until I see it break. That would be a solid few days of work though, so I think I'll keep it to a last resort.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention. I had a look for any 3rd party packages, but the only Nuget packages being used were the Microsoft ReportViewer Common and Microsoft Report Viewer Web Forms packages.

Comment: Welp, bounty is pretty much up, and the problem is still left unresolved. I've left you with a +2 score, so you should get half the bounty as a thank you, but I can't justify marking the answer as correct until the problem is solved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Jamie, thanks for that. Made my Friday ^_^. I will keep an eye and keep asking my colleagues though. Hope for the best.